# Difference between getParsedProgramAccounts vs getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner

Tags: web3.js

Just started learning solana development and I'm going over the cookbook. It uses this piece of code to retrieve tokens for a wallet

```
const accounts1 = await connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, {
  filters: [
    {
      dataSize: 165, // number of bytes
    },
    {
      memcmp: {
        offset: 32, // number of bytes
        bytes: walletAddress, // base58 encoded string
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

but I was wondering what was the difference between fetching the tokens like that (which seems more complicated) vs using getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner

```
const accounts2 = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(
  walletAddress,
  {
    programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  }
);
```

I get the same result for both

```
// getParsedProgramAccounts
[
  {
    account: {
      data: [Object],
      executable: false,
      lamports: 2039280,
      owner: [PublicKey],
      rentEpoch: 360
    },
    pubkey: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: 7e46e9307f3ef36b1972531c2d7b769c4efe109e37e00ee6668656c42ed66661>
    }
  }
],

// getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner
 [
  {
    account: {
      data: [Object],
      executable: false,
      lamports: 2039280,
      owner: [PublicKey],
      rentEpoch: 360
    },
    pubkey: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: 7e46e9307f3ef36b1972531c2d7b769c4efe109e37e00ee6668656c42ed66661>
    pubkey: PublicKey {
      _bn: <BN: 7e46e9307f3ef36b1972531c2d7b769c4efe109e37e00ee6668656c42ed66661>
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's literally no difference -- in fact, both of those queries will result in the same exact code paths in the RPC node.